# Purpose of reference on defined function

Tags: c++, accelerated-c++

I am going through accelerated c++ and have a question in regards to Chapter 4.  We go over referencing in this section, and I believe I understand its use to manipulate objects and variables.  However, what I really don't understand is why the author uses & to redefine a function already belonging to std class

Here is the code:
Student_info.cpp

```
istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{
    // read and store the student's name and midterm and final exam grades
    is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

    read_hw(is, s.homework);  // read and store all the student's homework grades
    return is;
}
```

main.cpp

```
while (read(cin, record)) {
        // find length of longest name
        maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
        students.push_back(record);
    }
```

Could someone please explain why we would do this?  Is it just for pedagogical reasons to show that we can?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what I really don't understand is why the author uses & to redefine a function already belonging to std class

He's not redefining a function.

**He's creating a new function, called `read`, that returns an `istream&`.**

The fact that it returns a reference is convention (matching the equivalent behaviour of standard library functions) but has very little to do with the fact that he's defining the function in the first place.

The standard library has no function with knowledge of the custom type `Student_info`.

Comment: Ok I see.  So we are creating a function read() that returns a reference to istream, is that right?  Would you be able to explain why we want to do this?  Does returning 'cin', as in this case, ask for another input, and therefore keeps our loop running until there is some invalid input within our function read()?

I appreciate the help so far.  I've been looking at examples over the internet to try to clarify as well. :)

Comment: @David: Yeah. By returning a reference to the stream, we permit checking the result of the extractions, since the stream object is convertible to a boolean that tells us its error state. `std::getline` works the same way. It's a convention used in the standard library.

Comment: Excellent. Than you for your help.  I feel like i am learning by osmosis :D. Slowly but surely.

Comment: @David: That's the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Because `Student_info` is a user-defined type and the istream operator needs to be overload it in order to know how to handle a `Student_info` parameter.

Think about operator overloading with mathematical operators and the same thing applies.

He uses & because he wants to return it as reference to the already created one so there is no unnecessary copy operations.

Comment: "Unnecessary" doesn't have anything to do with it: _streams cannot be copied_. They are flows of data, not containers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the clarification, I have to re-read Bjarne's book to keep my skills sharp, I can't believe I said that.